# how to using enter key and <a onclick > to submit a from?

Tags: javascript, jquery

see the codes bellow, I want to submit a form using "a" with onclick event. but I want to using "enter" keypress to do the same job. how to do it? this code bellow will not alert(1) when keypress "enter"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="filters.submit()">submit</a>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // how  to : input a name, then keypress "enter" ,will execute <filters.submit()> ,the same as click <a> to submit
    var filters={
        form: $('.filters').find('form'),
        submit: function (){
            alert(1);
            this.form.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why are you not using jQuery event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should attach the enter key to your `filters.submit()` method.

```
$(function() {
   $(document).keypress(function(event) {
     if (event.which == 13) {
        filters.submit();
     }  
   });
});
```

Comment: how can i know the cusor is focus in the input ?

Comment: If you only want the enter key to trigger the function if a field is in focus you would just replace `$(document)` with a selector for the desired field: `$('input[name="name"]')`